# How do I get the tables in an SSRS report to use the data in a dataset without multiple trips to the database

Tags: reporting-services, dataset, ssrs-tablix, reporting-services-2012

I have a dataset which has the data to be used in by several tables in my 2012 SSRS report.

Each table uses a different set of rows in the dataset, i.e. where a **particular column** in the dataset has a particular value.

I would like to grab all the data to be used by all the tables in one go, and then have the tables use the dataset's data, filtering by this particular column.

Unfortunately, it looks like the report fetches data into the dataset **every time** each table needs to be populated.

Is there a way I can get the table to use the data that has **already** been fetched into the dataset without it making the report refetch data into the dataset?

Comment: How do you currently filter the data - using Parameters or Filters?

Comment: I use filters *and* parameters. I need the parameters because the dataset is populated by a stored procedure which needs parameters as input. Then I use a filter to filter out the dataset, based on the particular column, as above.